Chrome Extension: content.js triggered only once whereas "url" is changing
I am new to Chrome Extensions ("CE") and JS.
Using CE with JS I am scraping data from a website while I visit it (active tab).
It works the first time I navigate a matching url (defined in the manifest.json) but I have to click refresh when I navigate to a new matching URL.
I would like to navigate and the script to run every time the pattern is matched.
my manifest.json file:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Scraper",
  "description": "Scrape product data from the active tab.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "abc.png",
    "32": "abc.png",
    "48": "abc.png",
    "128": "abc.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["webNavigation"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "scripts/content.js" 
      ],
      "matches": ["https://*.example.co.uk/search?*"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ]
}


my content.js file is like:
function scrapProductsFromSearch() {

      console.log("Scrapped the page");
  }

I beleive the issue is that I want my app to trigger whenever the "fragment" part has changed ie:

https://*.example.co.uk/search?ABC
https://*.example.co.uk/search?DEF
Should trigger the script..

My understanding is that, these 2 urls are not being accounted as different because there is no "/" after the "?".
Again I am new to this, and correct me if I al wrong.
So I guess the question is how to take into account these changes.
Any help would be much apreciated.
Thank you vm

See this answer.

@woxxom, I thought that MutationObserver was being used when there was JS changing the page. In my case I just want the script to run on any url that match my url pattern, after the page has been loaded. Am I missing something ? I am new to this. tx a lot for your time

It's a SPA (Single-Page Application) so it preserves the same initially constructed page and just changes the visible URL via History API and rewrites the DOM of the page to imitate real navigation. You need to match the entire site in matches and use MutationObserver.

Thankw a lot. so if I understand correctly, my code should work, and as it doesn't, the site I am visiting is actually an SPA. I wil llook into your other answer. tx again
